# Extending webpack output

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I'm trying to write Webpack plugin which will generate alias for each chunk defined inside entry. My idea was to generate alias which then I could use inside library property, just like we can use `[name]` or `[id]` in output. So my newly created plugin looks next:

```
function Aliasify(options) {
  this.options = options;
}

Aliasify.prototype.apply = function(compiler) {
  var self = this;
  compiler.plugin("compilation", function(compilation) {

    compilation.plugin("optimize", function() {
      compilation.chunks.forEach(function(chunk) {
        var alias = chunk.name.replace(self.options.searchFor, self.options.replaceWith);
        chunk.alias = alias;
      });
    }

};
```

This generates property alias for every chunk defined in entry.

Using the `[alias]` inside library property exposes the every chunk as `'[alias]'`  which isn't what i wanted.

```
library: ['gravity', 'gateway', '[alias]']
```

I hoped this will generate chunks with exposed `master` and `slave` which is the value of alias property inside chunk. My config.js looks next:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'master': './master.js',
    'master.min': './master.js',
    'slave': './slave.js',
    'slave.min': './slave.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new Clean(['dist']),
    new Uglify({
        include: /\.min\.js$/i,
        minimize: true
    }),
    new Aliasify({
        searchFor: '.min',
        replaceWith: ''
    })
  ],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    library: ['gravity', 'gateway', '[alias]'],
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true
  }
};
```

So the bottom line is:

- I want files created as `master.js`, `master.min.js`, `slave.js` and `slave.min.js` - this is ok using the name in filename prop
- I want library to be exposed as `master` inside `master.js`, `master.min.js` and `slave` in `slave.js`, `slave.min.js` , but  every chunk gets exposed as `[alias]`

Answer (score 0):

Found workaround for this. According to documentation webpack will accept an array of configurations. I used this to bundle files with completely different settings.

```
module.exports = [
  {
    entry: {
        'index' : './index.js',
        'master': './master.js',
        'slave': './slave.js',
        'plugin-storage': './plugin-storage.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new Clean(['dist']),
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        library: ['gravity', 'gateway', '[name]'],
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        umdNamedDefine: true
    }
  },
  {
    entry: {
        'index' : './index.js',
        'master': './master.js',
        'slave': './slave.js',
        'plugin-storage': './plugin-storage.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new Uglify({
            include: /\.js$/i,
            minimize: true
        })
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].min.js',
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        library: ['gravity', 'gateway', '[name]'],
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        umdNamedDefine: true
    }
  }
];
```